# Q: Google Drive API - Getting modified files

Tags: google-drive-api

When requesting a list of files modified since a certain time, does anyone know how long it takes for the response to show files after they has been modified?

I modified a file a little after 6/24 at 12:30am (which was a few minutes ago).  If I request a list of files that has been modified since 8:35pm on the previous day, the file shows up:

REQUEST (modifiedTime > "2017-06-23T21:30:00.000Z")

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=teamDrive&includeTeamDriveItems=true&orderBy=modifiedTime+desc&q=(trashed+!%3D+true)+AND+(NOT+(mimeType+contains+%22.folder%22))+AND+(modifiedTime+%3E+%222017-06-23T21%3A30%3A00.000Z%22)&supportsTeamDrives=true&teamDriveId=0AF36YeSWsu3dUk9PVA&fields=files(name%2Cid%2CfileExtension%2CmimeType%2CcreatedTime%2CmodifiedTime%2Csize%2CimageMediaMetadata(height%2Cwidth)%2Cparents%2CwebContentLink%2CheadRevisionId)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

RESPONSE

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "1gc9ooedN1YNQkMHqFuI-keekHvuN9h57ssz8Dn8cpU0",
   "name": "2017 Men's NCAA Wrap-Up",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
   "parents": [
    "0B4jAnSzS-VxlLVpBQ21KMjVMSE0"
   ],
   "createdTime": "2017-06-16T12:38:55.364Z",
   "modifiedTime": "2017-06-24T00:31:46.251Z"
  }
 ]
}
```

If I request a list of files that have been updated since 11:30pm on the previous day, it does not:

REQUEST (modifiedTime > "2017-06-23T23:30:00.000Z")

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=teamDrive&includeTeamDriveItems=true&orderBy=modifiedTime+desc&q=(trashed+!%3D+true)+AND+(NOT+(mimeType+contains+%22.folder%22))+AND+(modifiedTime+%3E+%222017-06-23T23%3A30%3A00.000Z%22)&supportsTeamDrives=true&teamDriveId=0AF36YeSWsu3dUk9PVA&fields=files(name%2Cid%2CfileExtension%2CmimeType%2CcreatedTime%2CmodifiedTime%2Csize%2CimageMediaMetadata(height%2Cwidth)%2Cparents%2CwebContentLink%2CheadRevisionId)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

RESPONSE

```
{
 "files": [
 ]
}
```

Eventually the file will show up in the list, but it does not seem to be a matter of minutes (I stopped clicking refresh after 5 minutes).  If I walk away for an hour or two, it shows up in the list.  Interestingly enough, the modifiedTime on the file is immediately correct if the file is returned in the response (see the first response above).  Is this a bug or should I expect to have to wait a certain period of time (and if so, how long) before the query returns the right results?

Comment: I don't think Google Docs has an answer for the definite time. Not sure if it fits your usecase but have you tried using [push notifications for Detect Changes docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) for tracking changes?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've found is that the time seems to vary.  I have switched to using the drive.changes.list method instead of the drive.files.list method with the "q" parameter.  Not only do changes appear sooner in the changes list, but you can actually see how long it was between the file "modifiedTime" and the change "time".  I have seen it range from seconds up to 10-15 minutes.

The other observation I had was that if I close the file in the browser, the change *immediately* appears in the changes list.  I guess Google auto saves the document at particular times.  I can't find a way to force a save while the document is open.  An explicit File | Save might be nice to have, but closing the window seems to do the trick.